# Script google form - mail confirmation htmlBody

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I use this script to send mail confirmation with attachment when a google form is complete. All is ok but i would like to use hmtl for the mail body.

Actually, i use "var htmlBody" but html is not interpreted in the mail confirmation.

Thanks for your help !

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[2];

  var subject = "Votre demande";
  var htmlBody = "Madame, Monsieur, <br>Veuillez trouver ci-joint le(s) documents demandés. Nous sommes à votre entière disposition pour vous apporter de l'aide dans votre recherche de mode de garde. Vous retrouverez toutes nos coordonnées en pièce jointe. <br>Bien cordialement,";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1KKDr2bIwi1k_nOi3DR-TlnLfDDHLwc7mdV8SL24db-k")
  var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById("1RCBty4E2MCuj1ZV3MGCmZxGFsA2bXUiVBwCxHGJJCU4")
  var pdfFile = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var pdfFile2 = file2.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  if (e.values[1] == "La liste des assistants maternels") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, htmlBody, {
      attachments: [pdfFile]
    });
  }
  if (e.values[1] == "Le dossier de pré-inscription en crèche") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, htmlBody, {
      attachments: [pdfFile2]
    });
  }
  if (e.values[1] == "La liste des assistants maternels, Le dossier de pré-inscription en crèche") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, htmlBody, {
      attachments: [pdfFile, pdfFile2]
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve your issue by moving `htmlBody`. There are 2 patterns for achieving what you want.

#### Pattern 1

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
  email,
  subject,
  "sample text", // If HTML can't be received, this is used.
  {
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    attachments: [pdfFile]
  }
);
```

#### Pattern 2

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: email,
  subject: subject,
  body: "sample text", // If HTML can't be received, this is used.
  htmlBody: htmlBody,
  attachments: [pdfFile]
});
```

#### Reference :

- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.